# qt get mouse clicked position relative to image in a graphics view

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qgraphicsview, qmouseevent

I want to allow user to draw lines on image using the mouse,
I'm using graphics view and mouse event but the position I get is not the right position relative to the image
here is the mouse event function

```
void InitializationDialog::mousePressEvent(QMouseEvent *event) {
    if(drawing) {
        points.append(event->pos());
        if(!points.isEmpty()) {
            if(points.size()==1) {
                QString fileName = list.at(choosed);
                QImage image(fileName);
                QGraphicsScene* scene = new QGraphicsScene();
                QGraphicsPixmapItem* item = new QGraphicsPixmapItem(QPixmap::fromImage(image));
                scene->addItem(item);
                QColor color(255,0,0);
                QBrush brush(color);
                QPen pen(brush, 4);
                QGraphicsLineItem* line = new QGraphicsLineItem(points.at(0).x(),points.at(0).y(),points.at(0).x()+1,points.at(0).y()+1);
                line->setPen(pen);
                scene->addItem(line);

                ui->graphicsView->setScene(scene);
                return;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

That should draw a point (I'm replacing it with one-pixel long line to look like a point)

Now I get the red point far away the mouse click like shown in that image
[image]

How can I make it exactly on the mouse cursor?

Edit:

I made a custom class for graphics scene to get the click relative to it, I tried overriding mouse pressed for graphics view but the scene is not the same size as graphics view and the point still away the mouse click

overriding mouse pressed in my custom scene didn't help much because I always get 0,0 position for clicking the scene no matter where I click

new files code:

header file

```
#ifndef INITGRAPH_H
#define INITGRAPH_H
#include <QtGui>
#include <QGraphicsView>
#include <QGraphicsScene>
#include <QPoint>
#include <QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent>
class InitGraph : public QGraphicsView {
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    InitGraph(QWidget *parent = 0);
    virtual ~InitGraph() {};
};

class CustomScene : public QGraphicsScene {
    Q_OBJECT
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event);
signals:
    void pressed(QPoint p);
};
#endif // INITGRAPH_H
```

the source file

```
#include "initgraph.h"
InitGraph::InitGraph(QWidget *parent):QGraphicsView(parent)
{
}
void CustomScene::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
    qDebug(QString::number(event->pos().rx()).toLatin1());
    QPoint p = event->pos().toPoint();
    emit pressed(p);
}
```

Comment: First of all I would suggest to handle the `mousePressEvent` of the QGraphicsScene (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qgraphicsscene.html#mousePressEvent)... Second, I would like to know why you create a new scene, pixmap- and line-item on each `mousePress`???

Comment: That is bad practice you are right, I was in a hurry so didn't notice, I will consider making them once and delete them at the destructor, thanks for reminding me

Comment: I will also check the link and let you know if I had any problems with it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to add a `QGraphicsLineItem` you must use the system coordinates of the scene for this you must use the function the `scenePos()` method of `QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent` and the method `mapFromScene()` of the items.

for this we must override the methods `mousePressEvent`, `mouseMoveEvent` and `mouseReleaseEvent` of `QGraphicsScene`, all of the above I implemented it in the following class:

```
class CustomScene : public QGraphicsScene
{
    Q_OBJECT
    QGraphicsLineItem *item;
protected:
    void mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){

        item = new QGraphicsLineItem;
        addItem(item);
        const QPointF p = event->scenePos();

        item->setPos(p);
    }

    void mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
        const QPointF p  =item->mapFromScene(event->scenePos());
        QLineF l = item->line();
        l.setP2(p);
        item->setLine(l);
    }

    void mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event){
        const QPointF p  =item->mapFromScene(event->scenePos());
        QLineF l = item->line();
        l.setP2(p);
        item->setLine(l);
    }

};
```

The complete code is on the following [link](https://github.com/eyllanesc/stackoverflow/tree/master/questions/46049009-qt-get-mouse-clicked-position-relative-to-image-in-a-graphics-view).

Comment: Awesome, that works, exactly scenepos instead of pos is the solution. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Since you are overloading mouse events of dialog you have the mouse position in dialog coordinates. It's better to use drawing widget events to let Qt make all the conversation for you and didn't filter dialog areas.

To make it really reusable you can implement the  QGraphicsItem Drawable subclass and process mouse events there adding or editing children.

**EDIT**
here is a working example for you [qt-drawable-item-example](https://github.com/asergunov/qt-drawable-item-example)

Briefly:

```
void DrawableItem::mousePressEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
    m_activePath = new QGraphicsPathItem(this);
    m_activePath->setPen(QPen(Qt::GlobalColor(rand()%17+2), 2.0));
    m_activePath->setPath(QPainterPath(event->pos()));
}

void DrawableItem::mouseMoveEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
    if(!m_activePath) {
        QGraphicsItem::mouseMoveEvent(event);
        return;
    }

    auto path = m_activePath->path();
    path.lineTo(event->pos());
    m_activePath->setPath(path);
}

void DrawableItem::mouseReleaseEvent(QGraphicsSceneMouseEvent *event) {
    if(!m_activePath) {
        QGraphicsItem::mouseReleaseEvent(event);
        return;
    }
    m_activePath = nullptr;
}
```

Comment: I did that for QGraphicsScene, how can I edit it to try QGraphicsItem instead? see the edit of the question

Comment: @AmmarAtef please check the edit of the answer. I've added repo link there.

Comment: Thanks that is great

Answer (score 1):

You are receiving position of click on InitializationDialog but not on your graphicsView, so you need to convert this position by minusing x and y of your graphicsView

```
QGraphicsLineItem* line = new QGraphicsLineItem(
                          points.at(0).x()-graphicsView->rect().x(), 
                          points.at(0).y()-graphicsView->rect().y(), 
                          points.at(0).x()+1, points.at(0).y()+1);
```

Comment: What is your hierarchy of views? Possibly you have some scroll view. Just implement mouse event inside of class that draws image.